# How to parse a TimeSpan value in Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, timespan

I'd like parse JSON string and use the `token.Type` property to detect values of type `JTokenType.TimeSpan`.

I can't work out how to express the TimeSpan in my input string, everything seems to be interpreted as JTokenType.String.

```
var timeSpanString = TimeSpan.FromHours(1).ToString();
testString = string.Format(@"{{""Value"": ""{0}"" }}", timeSpanString);
var statObject = JObject.Parse(testString);
JToken token = statObject["Value"];
var tokenValue = token.ToString();
var tokenType = token.Type; // JTokenType.String
```

I even tried:

```
JValue jValue = new JValue("test");
jValue.Value = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
bool isTimeSpan = jValue.Type == JTokenType.TimeSpan; // true!
testString = string.Format(@"{{""Value"": ""{0}"" }}", jValue.Value);
var statObject = JObject.Parse(testString);
JToken token = statObject["Value"];
var tokenValue = token.ToString();
var tokenType = token.Type; // JTokenType.String
```

Which at least produces a **JValue** object of tokenType JTokenType.TimeSpan, but still shows up as a JTokenType.String when I parse it.

This works perfectly for DateTime objects.
How can I express the input string such that the parsed value type is `JTokenType.TimeSpan` ?

Comment: Are you looking at processing input with a certain structure, or are you wanting to find any instance of a timespan in a block of Json?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a certain structure".
The input will be a JSON string containing a value which can be one of multiple types: string, DateTime, TimeSpan and some others.

Comment: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); var ts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeSpan>(json);`

Comment: @L.B - That doesn't really help. I need to know how to format the input string such that the parser turns this string into JObject which contains a JValue token of type JTokenType.TimeSpan

Comment: @sd The existance of the serializers is to hide those details from you.  Just rethink about that.

Comment: But your solution doesn't solve my specific problem: 
var ts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

testString = string.Format(@"{{""Value"": {0} }}", ts); 

var statObject = JObject.Parse(testString); 

JToken token = statObject["Value"]; 

var tokenValue = token.ToString(); var tokenType = token.Type; // JTokenType.String - expect JTokenType.TimeSpan 

My code has to take the deserialized object and behave differently for different types.

Comment: This method worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14319926/298573

Answer (score 6):

Based on what I've seen while using JSON.NET for a while now, you will never, with the default settings, parse a string and retrieve a token with type `JTokenType.TimeSpan` (same for some other types as well, such as Guid or Uri). I have a pretty good guess of why this is the case (based on my experience working a few years ago with the `DataContractJsonSerializer`).

Basically, it's a matter of how much information the parser can retrieve out of the input. JSON is a very simple syntax which only knows about *numbers*, *boolean* and *strings* (in addition to arrays and objects). Many CLR types don't have a native JSON type (Uri, DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and so on), so when any JSON parser is reading the data, it will try to use the best match.

If you're deserializing the JSON string into a CLR data type, then the serializer has some additional information that it can use to disambiguate what a JSON string maps to - the type of the field / property that value is being deserialized to. However, when you're deserializing a JSON data to a `JToken` object graph, there's no additional information, and JSON.NET has to choose one type. The most natural type to deserialize a JSON string is, well, a CLR string.

But why do dates are deserialized correctly as `JTokenType.Date`? IIRC, the JSON.NET reader has a special code for dates (controlled by the `DateParseHandling` enumeration), which tries to match the parsed strings to some predefined formats (either ISO 8601 or the old Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX format), and if it finds a string which match it, it will read it as a `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`) instead of a string. I don't know whether it's possible to extend that behavior to also support `TimeSpan` or other types, but I wouldn't be surprised, since the extensibility in JSON.NET is quite good.

Comment: More info on the "magic" date/time parsing and how to avoid it: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to parse a TimeSpan it needs to be surrounded in quotations:
'"12:00:00"'

If you serialize a TimeSpan and look at the string result it looks like:
"\"12:00:00\""

At least this worked for me using NewtonSoft.JsonConvert. The string in my DB "12:00:00" (including the quotes).

And using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dbString) returns fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem and was able to do it this way:

```
string json = "{ \"span\": \"00:00:15\"}";

JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);

TimeSpan span = token["span"].ToObject<TimeSpan>();
```