# Serializing and deserializing TimeSpan values to a property of type Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class that has a field of type Object that may contain a TimeSpan object.

I am serializing this and the deserializing this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public object myTimeSpan { get; set; }
}

...

var myObject = new MyObject { myTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

...

var duplicateObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

And when I do, duplicateObject.myTimeSpan contains the string "2:00:00".

How can I get this to deserialize into a TimeSpan object?

Two points:

1. I'm not dealing with strings that have been serialized somewhere else. The only strings I'll be deserializing are strings that I serialized.
2. The field has to be of type object - it might contain a string, or a DateTime, or it might contain a TimeSpan. Currently, it's only the TimeSpan I'm having problems with.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. What is 'selectionCriteria' you are actually serializing?

Comment: I assume you meant `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);`.  If I do that, I get the JSON `{"myTimeSpan":"2.00:00:00"}`, and the duplicated object has a 2-day time span.

Comment: Sorry.  Cut-and-paste error - fixed.

Comment: I don't get a TimeSpan object, when the underlying field is of type object.

Comment: You may need to implement a custom `JsonConverter` that can try to parse the string representation of the `TimeSpan` back into an actual `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: The [JSON file format](http://json.org/) does not have a built-in value type for `TimeSpan` (or `DateTime`).  Its value types are string, number, object, array, `true`, `false` and `null`.  So, your `TimeSpan` gets converted to a string, and when read back in, JSON.net doesn't know any better than to keep it that way.   You probably need to change your serialized data format to indicate the object type somewhere.

Comment: Does you class really **need** a single `object` type field? Could you have three different fields, one for a `DateTime`, one for a `TimeSpan`, and one for a string, and then have your business logic assign the input to the correct field?

Comment: Nope.  It's a generic function that needs to operator on damned-near any type. I'm thinking I'm going to need to add a field to the class that contains the type of the object.

Comment: This method worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14319926/298573

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Json.Net has a `TypeNameHandling` setting for dealing with unknown types such that they can be deserialized properly.  When this setting is turned on, it causes Json.Net to insert special `$type` properties into the JSON which are then used as hints when deserializing.  Unfortunately, this setting  does not seem to work with "simple" types such as `TimeSpan`, because their values are serialized as  strings rather than objects.

To work around this issue, I would suggest making a custom `JsonConverter` that uses the same idea.  Instead of outputting the string value of the object directly, the converter would output a sub-object representation with two properties: `type` and `value`.  The `type` property of the sub-object would contain the assembly-qualified type name for the object, while the `value` property would contain the actual serialized value.  On deserialization, the converter would look for the `type` property to know what type of object to instantiate from the value property.  The nice thing about this approach is you do not have to add any additional properties or logic to your model class(es).

Here is how it might look in code:

```
class UnknownObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo["type"] = value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        jo["value"] = JToken.FromObject(value, serializer);
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Type type = Type.GetType(jo["type"].ToString(), throwOnError: true);
        return jo["value"].ToObject(type, serializer);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just decorate any `object` properties in your classes that need special handling with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnknownObjectConverter))]
    public object MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a round-trip demo which shows how this can work for several different types.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject { MyValue = TimeSpan.FromDays(2) },
            new MyObject { MyValue = "foo" },
            new MyObject { MyValue = new DateTime(2014, 12, 20, 17, 06, 44) },
            new MyObject { MyValue = new Tuple<int, bool>(23, true) }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
        foreach (MyObject obj in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.MyValue.GetType().Name + ": " + obj.MyValue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[
  {
    "MyValue": {
      "type": "System.TimeSpan, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "value": "2.00:00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "MyValue": {
      "type": "System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "value": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "MyValue": {
      "type": "System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "value": "2014-12-20T17:06:44"
    }
  },
  {
    "MyValue": {
      "type": "System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "value": {
        "Item1": 23,
        "Item2": true
      }
    }
  }
]

TimeSpan: 2.00:00:00
String: foo
DateTime: 12/20/2014 5:06:44 PM
Tuple`2: (23, True)
```

Comment: Under ReadJson, you first need to check for a null type or else you will get an Exception when serializing null types.

if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
    return null;

Comment: It was suspiciously hard to find an example of serialization outcome for *TimeSpan*. I noticed that sending in an *int* 4 produced time span of four days but that I wasn't able to pass in *double* like 0.25. Luckily, I noticed in your answer the format "d.hh:mm:ss". Thanks and +1.