# json.net IValueProvider SetValue thrown exception is lost

Tags: c#, exception, json.net

I have a `CotractResolver` that returns properties for Time part of each `DateTime` property (so that user can set time separately).
I have a `TimeValueProvider` that has a `SetValue` method as follows:

```
public void SetValue(object target, object value)
{
    try
    {
        var time = value as string;
        var originalValue = _propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
        if (value == null)
        {
            _propertyInfo.SetValue(target, originalValue);
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(time))
        {
            var originalDateTime = (DateTime?) originalValue ?? SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
            _propertyInfo.SetValue(target,
                new DateTime(originalDateTime.Year, originalDateTime.Month, originalDateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            var currentValue = GetCurrentValue(_propertyInfo.GetValue(target));
            var convertedDate = TimeSpan.Parse(time, new DateTimeFormatInfo {LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss"});
            var finalValue = new DateTime(currentValue.Year, currentValue.Month, currentValue.Day,
                convertedDate.Hours, convertedDate.Days, convertedDate.Seconds);
            _propertyInfo.SetValue(target, finalValue);
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidDataException)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(new[]
        {
            new ValidationError
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Time is not correct",
                FieldName = _propertyInfo.Name,
                TypeName = _propertyInfo.DeclaringType.FullName
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I pass an invalid number as time say for example 99:99 an exception is thrown by `TimeSpan.Parse` but I am not getting it outside this method thus `Json.Net` deserializes the object.
I have chekced my code and couldn't find any general exception handling in place that causes such behavior.
Am I missing something about contract resolvers and value providers here ?

UPDATE: here's how I have configured `Json.net` :

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new EntityContractResolver();
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
              config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Comment: Could you expand your question to a full [mcve], please?  I tried to reproduce your problem in a console app and could not, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Edraqz.  What I did observe is that your `TimeValueProvider.SetValue()` method is not called because Json.NET fails to parse the JSON string - and `SetValue()` is called only after the value has been *successfully* deserialized.  Maybe you want to use a [custom converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to parse the JSON string inside [`IValueProvider.SetValue()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IValueProvider_SetValue.htm).  However, the value provider is only called *after the JSON has been deserialized*.  Its purpose is to set the deserialized value inside the container object.  Thus your current `SetValue()` method never actually does anything, because:

- The incoming `object value` will be a `DateTime` not a string if deserialization was successful.
- The method will not be called at all if the date string was invalid, because an exception will already have been thrown.

What you need to do instead is use a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to parse the JSON date string and combine it with the existing value.  [`JsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) has an argument `existingValue` that contains the current value of the property, so this is straightforward:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Date)
        {
            // Json.NET already parsed the date successfully.  Return it.
            return (DateTime)token;
        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan span;
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.TimeSpan)
            {
                // Not sure this is actually implemented, see
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484540/how-to-parse-a-timespan-value-in-newtonsoft-json/13505910#13505910
                span = (TimeSpan)token;
            }
            else
            {
                var timeString = (string)token;
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(timeString))
                    span = new TimeSpan();
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        span = TimeSpan.Parse(timeString, new DateTimeFormatInfo { LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss" });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ValidationException(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            var currentValue = (DateTime?)existingValue ?? SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;

            // Combine currentValue & TimeSpan and return.  REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR OWN LOGIC.
            // I don't really know how you want to do this.
            return new DateTime(currentValue.Year, currentValue.Month, currentValue.Day) + span;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then apply it in your `EntityContractResolver` as follows:

```
public class EntityContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    DateTimeConverter converter = null;

    DateTimeConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            if (converter == null)
                converter = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref converter, new DateTimeConverter(), null);
            return converter;
        }
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var jProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (jProperty.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || jProperty.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            jProperty.Converter = jProperty.MemberConverter = Converter;
        }
        return jProperty;
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ue0sIf).

Comment: Thanks for your complete and precise answer :)